# Meteor - dburles googlemaps package autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

this is a question regarding the Meteor package - `dburles:google-maps`. I managed to add it correctly and I have a google map, however I am trying to add additional functionality to it, especially the autocomplete plugin. [Autocomplete for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) Looking at the documentation for it, I am not sure what parts of the code are already included in the `dburles:google-maps`, as the syntax for initiating the map is different than the original docs from Google. 
My question is what sections of the documentation code should I consider when looking at it, and what should I ignore as it is included in the package already?

**My code for displaying a working google map**

***map.html***

```
<template name="map">
  <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="locations" options=locationsOptions}}
  </div>
</template>
```

**map.js**

```
// Loading map on startup
Meteor.startup(function() {
  GoogleMaps.load();
});

Template.map.helpers({
  locationsOptions: function() {
    // Make sure the maps API has loaded
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      // Map initialization options
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290),
        zoom: 12
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Look at the source code for the package, it's super simple & about 100 lines iirc. All it does is a lazy load of the closed-source google script & namespaces the map instance. Just load the autocomplete library at startup & you'll be good to go.

Comment: I have to have an API key to be able to implement this right? Because I managed to get a map working with the package without getting an API key?